# Cannot run Google ML engine locally due to Tensorflow issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to run the Google Cloud ML engine locally for debugging purposes by running the command `gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=fasttext_cloud/ --json-instances=debug_instance.json`. However, I'm getting the error: `ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) Cannot import Tensorflow.`

This is strange as Tensorflow works fine on my machine. Even a simple example like `python -c 'import tensorflow'` has no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Is TensorFlow installed in a virtual environment or a non-standard location that isn't on the Python path when running from gcloud?

Its a bit kludgy but I would do the following to check the Python path being used by gcloud. Modify the file

```
${GCLOUD_INSTALL_LOCATION}/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/ml_engine/__init__.py
```

At the top of the file add

```
import sys
print("\n".join(sys.path))
```

Then run

```
gcloud ml-engine
```

This should print out the python path and you can now check that it includes the location where TensorFlow is installed.

Comment: It's installed using anaconda, not in a virtual environment. It's available when running `python -c 'import tensorflow'` so I would think that it's on the Python path. However, I can try to examine that more if you give me a bit of guidance how to do that?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a suggestion on how to check the path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to the latest gcloud release (171.0.0) and retry?
To upgrade, run

$ gcloud components update